# C++ “add explicit braces to avoid dangling else”

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

```
bool isPalindromeIterative(const char *s1){

int len=strlen(s1)-1;

if(len>0)
    if(s1[0]==s1[len]){
        len-=2;
        isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
    else

        return false;

return true;
}
```

I am writing about Palindrome.
And when I run it, it appears warning like this:

":79:13: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else
      [-Wdangling-else]"

Please help me ! Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear about that warning?

Comment: It's not clear which `if` the `else` belongs to. Brackets will clear that up.

Comment: I add else { return false;} like this, it still warns like that.

Comment: Try putting the braces at another place too. You have two if-statements.

Comment: 79:13: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else
      [-Wdangling-else]
            else
            ^

Comment: I think is a good practice (almost) always use brackets

Comment: Side note: the func is called `isPalindromeIterative` but you are calling it recursively.

Comment: The warning you noticed is not from 'running it'.  It is a compiler report generated by the compiler.  No executable has yet been generated.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write,

```
if(len>0)
    if(s1[0]==s1[len]){

        // This has no effect on the recursive call.
        len-=2;

        // You missed the return in your post.
        return isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
    else
        return false;
```

it's most likely that you meant to associate the `else` with the second `if`.

```
if(len>0)
{
    if(s1[0]==s1[len])
    {
        return isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

However, the compiler does not use the indent to figure that out. It's possible that, from the compiler writer's point of view, you meant to associate the `else` with the first `if`:

```
if(len>0)
{
    if(s1[0]==s1[len])
    {
        return isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Since this is common mistake made by developers, the compiler warns you and hopes that you will update the code so that it's less likely to turn into a runtime error.

---

I want to point out that the recursion logic you are using to detect whether a string is palindrome is wrong.

Let's say your string is "abxba".

In the first iteration, you compare `'a'` with `'a'`.
In the next iteration, you compare `'b'` with `'a'`, which is incorrect. You end up with the wrong answer.

You have to change your strategy a bit. Use:

```
bool isPalindromeIterative(const char *s1, int start, int end)
{
   if ( start >= end )
   {
      return true;
   }

   if ( s1[start] == s1[end] )
   {
      return isPalindromeIterative(s1, start+1, end-1)
   }

   return false;
}
```

The start of the iterative call has to be made as:

```
isPalindromeIterative(s1, 0, strlen(s1)-1);
```

Comment: To be absolutely clear: from the compiler's point of view, that `else` is associated with the inner `if`. The point of the warning is that sometimes that's not what was intended.

Comment: @PeteBecker, true. Perhaps the "compiler writer's" is more appropriate.

Comment: : warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] } ^

Comment: Do you know why..? Thanks!

Comment: You must have removed the `return true;` that is before the last `}` in your function.

Comment: Do you know how to modify to ignore the influence of upper or lower ?

Comment: @王小泉, you can use `if ( std::tolower(s1[0]) == std::tolower(s1[len]) )`.

Answer (score 6):

There is formally nothing wrong with the code, unless you wanted the `else` to match the outer `if`. A common mistake.

If you add braces everywhere, it will be clear what you intended:

```
if(len>0)
{
    if(s1[0]==s1[len])
    {
        len-=2;
        isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a style warning against reading the if clauses wrong.

```
if(len>0) {
    if(s1[0]==s1[len]){
        len-=2;
        isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

is better to read and less error-prone.
We have similar coding guidelines in our company; for an `if`, which has bracket clauses, all `else` branches and all other `if`s within the `if` of the highest order have to have brackets.

Else your example could too easily be misread as e.g.

```
if(len>0)
    if(s1[0]==s1[len]){
        len-=2;
        isPalindromeIterative(s1+1);
    }
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original post headline mentioned iterative, and 'Iterative' is still part of your function name (even though it is recursive).

You marked this post as c++, but did not use classes.

The other answers addressed your specific questions about your error messages.

---

For your consideration, and because you have already selected a recursive answer, here is a possible C++ **iterative** solution **and tail-recursive** solution using **std::string&**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class T589_t
{
public:

   int exec(int argc, char* argv[])
      {
         if (argc < 2)
         {
            std::cerr << "\n  please provide one or more string(s) to test" 
                      << std::endl;
            return -1;
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
         {
            std::string s = argv[i];
            {
               std::string yesno = (isPalindromeIterative(s) ? " is" : " is not");
               std::cout << "\n  '" << s << "'" << yesno << " a palindrome (iterative)" << std::flush;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            {
               std::string yesno = (isPalindromeRecursive(s) ? " is" : " is not");
               std::cout << "  '" << s << "'" << yesno << " a palindrome (recursive)" << std::endl;
            }
         } // for 0..argc

         return 0;
      }

private: // methods


   bool isPalindromeIterative(const std::string& s1)
      {  //         ^^^^^^^^^
         bool retVal = false;                           // guess s1 is not palindrome
         int   left  = 0;                               // index of left most char
         int   right = static_cast<int>(s1.size()) - 1; // index of right most char

         do { // iterative loop

            if (s1[left] != s1[right]) break; // when not equal, is not palindrome

            left += 1;  right -= 1;  // iterate!

            if (left >= right)  // all chars tested?
            {
               retVal = true;   // confirm palindrome
               break;           // exit
            }

         } while (true); 

         return retVal;
      }

   // Notes    './dumy589'  // odd length 9
   //           ^-------^   [0] vs [8]
   //            ^-----^    [1] vs [7]
   //             ^---^     [2] vs [6]
   //              ^-^      [3] vs [5]
   //               ^       [4] == [4]  // left >= right, break

   // Notes     'abccba'    // even length 6
   //            ^----^     [0] vs [5]
   //             ^--^      [1] vs [4]
   //              ^^       [2] vs [3]
   //                       [3] vs [2]  // left >= right, break

   // Notes     'abcba'     // odd length 5
   //            ^---^      [0] vs [4]
   //             ^-^       [1] vs [3]
   //              ^        [2] vs [2]  // left >= right, break


   // and bonus: tail recursion based on above iterative     
   //               vvvvvvvvv
   bool isPalindromeRecursive(const std::string& s1)
      {
         // index of left most char
         int   left  = 0;          
         // index of right most char
         int   right = static_cast<int>(s1.size()) - 1; 

         return (isPalindromeRecursive(s1, left, right));
      }

   bool isPalindromeRecursive(const std::string& s1, int left, int right)
      {
         if (s1[left] != s1[right]) return false;
         left += 1;   right -= 1;
         if (   left  >=    right ) return true;
         return (isPalindromeRecursive(s1, left, right));
      }
}; // class T589_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   T589_t  t589;
   return  t589.exec(argc, argv);
}
```

On Linux, argv[0] is the executable name.

environment:
   Lubuntu 17.10, 
   g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0

With invocation:

```
./dumy589 aba abccba tx s
```

This code reports:

```
  './dumy589' is not a palindrome (iterative)
  './dumy589' is not a palindrome (recursive)

  'aba' is a palindrome (iterative)
  'aba' is a palindrome (recursive)

  'abccba' is a palindrome (iterative)
  'abccba' is a palindrome (recursive)

  'tx' is not a palindrome (iterative)
  'tx' is not a palindrome (recursive)

  's' is a palindrome (iterative)
  's' is a palindrome (recursive)
```